# how to provide multiprocessing.process unique variblables

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I have a list containing ID Number's, I want to implement every unique ID Number in an API call for each Multiprocessor whilst running the same corresponding functions, implementing the same conditional statements to each processor etc. I have tried to make sense of it but there is not a lot online about this procedure.

I thought to use a for loop but I don't want every processor running this for loop picking up every item in a list. I just need each item to be associated to each processor.

I was thinking something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import process 
import requests, json

ID_NUMBERS = ["ID 1", "ID 2", "ID 3".... ETC]
BASE_URL = "www.api.com"
KEY = {"KEY": "12345"}

a = 0

for x in ID_NUMBERS:
    def[a]():
        while Active_live_data == True:
            # continuously loops over, requesting data from the website
            unique_api_call = "{}/livedata[{}]".format(BASE_URL, x)
            request_it = requests.get(unique_api_call, headers=KEY)
            show_it = (json.loads(request_it.content))

            #some extra conditional code...

        a += 1

processes = []
b = 0

for _ in range(len(ID_NUMBERS))
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = b)
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)    
    b += 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kindest regards,

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `map` function:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
num_cores = mp.cpu_count()
pool = mp.Pool(processes=num_cores)
results = pool.map(your_function, list_of_IDs)
```

This will execute the function `your_function`, each time with a different item from the list `list_of_IDs`, and the values returned by `your_function` will be stored in a list of values (`results`).

Answer (score 1):

Same approach as @AlessiaM but uses the high-level api in the `concurrent.futures` module.

```
import concurrent.futures as mp
import requests, json

BASE_URL = ''
KEY = {"KEY": "12345"}
ID_NUMBERS = ["ID 1", "ID 2", "ID 3"]

def job(id):
    unique_api_call = "{}/livedata[{}]".format(BASE_URL, id)
    request_it = requests.get(unique_api_call, headers=KEY)
    show_it = (json.loads(request_it.content))
    return show_it

# Default to as many workers as there are processors,
# But since your job is IO bound (vs CPU bound), 
# you could increase this to an even bigger figure by giving the `max_workers` parameter
with mp.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
    results = pool.map(job,ID_NUMBERS)

# Process results here
```

Comment: thank you for your help, just to clarify what I am reading, the 'id' from 'def job(id)' will input the 'ID_NUMBERS' item one at a time? Does this example create multiple processes dependant on how many cores/threads my device can handle too?

Comment: That's correct @andrewenglish, like a regular map function works on an iterable.

Comment: And yes creates as many processes as you have processors on your machine. But if you want to increase or decrease the no of processes, you can say with mp.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool if you want

Comment: Thank you! just to double check, 'max_workers' are the threads, not cores?

Comment: As `concurrent.futures` is a high-level layer, `max_workers` is the number of processes if using a `ProcessPoolExecutor` and number of threads if using a `ThreadPoolExecutor`. So in the code above, it will create as many processes(not threads) as there are processors on the machine.